# What is the symbol on Konohamaru's sleeve?

Tags: boruto

In Boruto, Konohamaru has a symbol on a band on his sleeve. It looks a bit like the USB symbol (or a cross between a stick figure and a salamander), though obviously that's not what it is. What is it and what does it represent?

[image: Konohamaru with armband]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the symbol of the [Sarutobi Clan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sarutobi_Clan) of which he is a member.